# Use of standardization or normalization's parameters in training/validation/test

Tags: machine-learning, normalization, data-processing

It is best practice to normalize/standardize the training set and then, with its parameters, (`min` & `max` for normalization and `mean` & `std` for standardization) normalize/standardize the validation set.

What I was wondering was the effect of having in the validation set different min/max values and therefore ending up with values whose range is no more within the interval (0,1).

How this affects the training of a neural network?

Last doubt: what about when we use the test set to evaluate model's performance over unseen data, should we again normalized/standardize the data with the training parameters? Since these parameters are actually tied together with the trained model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scale, you usually know the extent of your data:

- for an image, you go from 0-255 to 0-1, that's fine, you know the range beforehand
- for other features, what you are scaling is not a uniform distribution, but a Gaussian distribution, in which case you must not be not constrained by the [0,1] interval for the output (or [-1,1]).

So usually, if you know what kind of output you want (probability or image), you also know the real complete range you can have for the input.

When you don't know the input range, you usually don't want to have a sigmoid at the output because that constrains your network more than you should.

And yes, you need to use the same preprocessing pipeline as for your training data, meaning the trained normalization parameters.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am not using a sigmoid at the output. I am working on an autoencoder that leverages multi features sensor data, which I can not predict and give an extent at priori. Thank you for your answer, so I should not be constrained by the [0,1] [-1,1] intervals

Comment: Indeed, that's perfectly fine if you don't have [-1,1]. You will not have it anyway if you are dividing by the standard deviation of your data.